# Convert 24h to 12h datetime format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want a datetime variable which will be having 12 hour datetime format.

Below example converts date in 12 hour but not helpful because it is in `VARCHAR` format, if tries to convert in datetime it shows like `2016-03-08 00:00:00.000-`

```
declare @t datetime = NULL

set @t = '2016-03-08 00:00:00'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, @t, 100) AS DateTime_In_12h_Format
```

I want a variable which will be holding 12 hour format something like this

```
declare @t datetime = NULL

set @t = '2016-03-08 00:00:00'

set @t = CONVERT(datetime, @t, 100)

select @t -> this should be -> Mar  8 2016 12:00AM
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: `datetime` variables don't have a format. Internally, they're a count of the number of days (and partial days) since 01/01/1900. Formats only apply when you convert to or from *strings*. You cannot get what you're asking for.

Comment: Yes Damien. I was thinking 24h was problem I facing but it has nothing to do with format. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the current datetime for example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, getdate(), 100) AS DateTime_In_12h_Format
```

Instead of getdate() you can put your desired column in a query (such as tdate in your example). If you want JUST the time in 12h and not the date and time use substring/right to separate them. It seems that you already know how to =).

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) lists every datetime conversion. It's really handy if you need other types of conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Declare one more `varchar` to save new `datetime`

```
declare @t datetime = NULL
declare @t1 varchar(20) = NULL
set @t = '2016-03-08 00:00:00'
set @t1 = CONVERT(varchar(20), @t, 100) 
select @t1 as DateTime_In_12h_Format
```

Comment: I want t1 to be datetime not varchar :)

Comment: @RohitDhage Formatting only applies character data types. If you want to change the display format of a DATETIME datatype, without converting to a character data type, you'll have to do it outside of SQL Server.